# List of Best Practice MySQL Data Types

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a list of best practice MySQL data types for common applications. For example, the list would contain the best data type and size for id, ip address, email, subject, summary, description content, url, date (timestamp and human readable), geo points, media height, media width, media duration, etc

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i don't know of any, so let's start one!

**numeric ID/auto_increment primary keys:** use an unsigned integer. do not use 0 as a value. and keep in mind the maximum value of of the various sizes, i.e. don't use int if you don't need 4 billion values when the 16 million offered by mediumint will suffice.

**dates:** unless you specifically need dates/times that are outside the supported range of mysql's DATE and TIME types, use them! if you instead use unix timestamps, you have to convert them to use the built-in date and time functions. if your app needs unix timestamps, you can always convert the standard date and time data types on the way out using `unix_timestamp()`.

**ip addresses:** use [`inet_aton()` and `inet_ntoa()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) since it easily compacts an ip address in to 4 bytes and gives you the ability to do range searches that utilize indexes.

Answer (score 8):

**Integer Display Width** You likely define your integers something like this "INT(4)" but have been baffled by the fact that (4) has no real effect on the stored numbers. In other words, you can store numbers like 999999 just fine. The reason is that for integers, (4) is the display width, and only has an effect if used with the ZEROFILL modifier. Further, this is for display purposes only, so you could define a column as "INT(4) ZEROFILL" and store 99999. If you stored 999, the mysql REPL (console) would output 0999 when you've selected this column.

In other words, if you don't need the ZEROFILL stuff, you can leave off the display width.

Answer (score 6):

**Money:** Use the Decimal data type. Based on real-world production scenarios I recommend (19,8).

EDIT: My original recommendation was (19,4); however, I've recently run into a production issue where the client reported that they absolutely needed decimal with a "scale" of "8"; thus "4" wasn't enough and was causing improper tax calculations. I now recommend (19,8) based on a real-world scenario. I would love to hear stories needing a more granular scale.